# IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, entitymanager, named-parameters

I pass a Map as parameter of the following method:

```
    public List<User> getByParameterOrAll(Map<String, String> paramsMap) {
    String email = null;
    String emailValue = null;
    String phone = null;
    String phoneValue = null;

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = paramsMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();
        if (entry.getKey().equals("email")){
            email = entry.getKey();
            emailValue = entry.getValue();
        } else if (entry.getKey().equals("phone")){
            phone = entry.getKey();
            phoneValue = entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    List<User> users = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email=:emailValue AND u.phone=:phoneValue", User.class).
            setParameter(emailValue, email).
            setParameter(phoneValue, phone).
            getResultList();
    return users;
}
```

And I catch for the line    "setParameter(emailValue, email)"

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [gmail@gmail.com], expecting one of [phoneValue, emailValue]
```

I attach the screen of my test

[image: Testing_screen]

Comment: What are the values of `paramsMap`

Comment: You passed variables to ```setParameter``` instead of parameter names. You need to change ```setParameter(emailValue, email)``` into ```setParameter("emailValue", emailValue)```. Same goes for phoneValue

Comment: By the way, if you already know the expected keys for email and phone, dont iterate over map entries and prefer to query the map by key => ```emailValue = paramsMap.get("email")```

Comment: YCF_L.  Dont unrestand clearly your question

Comment: Neywat. Thank you - I understand mu mistake now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should correct your query in the following way (see the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-query-parameters)) :

```java
List<User> users = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email=:emailValue AND u.phone=:phoneValue", User.class).
            setParameter("emailValue", email).
            setParameter("phoneValue", phone).
            getResultList();
```